# urlfetch.fetch got missed content within script tag of html in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, fetch, urlfetch

in my app, when I use urlfetch.fetch function to fetch a specified url, I found the content I got is empty for some special html codes.

for example, the url: http://www.club.cn.sodexo.com/node/5071
in real html source, the codes including:

```
<div class="content">
<div style="width: 219px; height: 262px;" id="gmap-auto3map-gmap0" class="gmap-control gmap-gmap gmap gmap-map gmap-auto3map-gmap">Javascript is required to view this map.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery.extend(true, Drupal, { settings: { "gmap": { "auto3map":{ "width": "219px", "height": "262px", "zoom": 16, "maxzoom": "17","controltype": "Large", "align": "None", "maptype": "Map", "mtc":"none", "baselayers": { "Map": 1, "Satellite": 1, "Hybrid": 1 },"styles": { "line_default": [ "0000ff", "5", "45", "", "" ],"poly_default": [ "000000", "3", "25", "ff0000", "45" ] },"line_colors": [ "#00cc00", "#ff0000", "#0000ff" ], "behavior":{ "autozoom": true }, "markermode": "0", "id": "auto3map", "latitude":"31.239132", "longitude": "121.483506", "markers": [ { "latitude":"31.239132", "longitude": "121.483506", "markername": "small red","offset": 0, "opts": { "title": "克莉丝汀食品（宁波路店）" }, "text": "\x3cdiv class=\"gmap-popup\"\x3e\x3c/div\x3e" } ] } } } });
/* ]]> */
</script>
</div>
```

but from what I got through url fetch:
the result would be:

```
<div class="content">
<div style="width: 219px; height: 262px;" id="gmap-auto3map-gmap0" class="gmap-control gmap-gmap gmap gmap-map gmap-auto3map-gmap">Javascript is required view this map.</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

All the javascript codes between `/* <![CDATA[ */` and `/* ]]> */` is missed, which is so wired. Anyone knows the problem? Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: I got the response from the developer of Google App Engine team at the official Google Groups, http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/98fe927edd02128e, in which he said that the User-Agent may be the major causing. But in my curl testing, the response did contain all the content including javascript codes. Till now, there is no further replay.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the server inserts different javascript based on the user-agent (ie different code for Firefox verses Internet Explorer), and for `urlfetch`'s user-agent the server gets confused and doesn't insert any javascript at all.